# Simplify this expression: $ \left((p\to q) \land (q \to r)\right)\to (p \to r)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

how to prove that expression is a tautology by using law of logic?? Thank you in instant

Comment: "law of logic" is a bit vague. What have you done so far?

Comment: What are you allowed to se as the "laws of logic"? make a truth table? Boolean laws?